# Vagrant SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status

Tags: docker, vagrant, virtualbox, dockerfile, vagrantfile

I'm trying to install docker on Ubuntu 18.04-VM (via vagrant) using the setup below. Is there any way I can make docker installation succeed on vagrant ubuntu 18.04 VM using the Vagrantfile? Note: I need to know how to apply the suggested solution into the Vagrantfile.

## Vagrantfile:

```
servers=[
  {
    :hostname => "manager",
    :ip => "192.168.2.1",
    :box => "ubuntu/bionic64",
    :ram => 2048,
    :cpu => 4
  },
  {
    :hostname => "worker-1",
    :ip => "192.168.2.2",
    :box => "ubuntu/bionic64",
    :ram => 2048,
    :cpu => 4
  },
  {
    :hostname => "worker-2",
    :ip => "192.168.2.3",
    :box => "ubuntu/bionic64",
    :ram => 2048,
    :cpu => 4
  }
]
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  servers.each do |machine|
    config.vm.define machine[:hostname] do |node|
      node.vm.box = machine[:box]
      node.vm.hostname = machine[:hostname]
      node.vm.network "private_network", ip: machine[:ip]
      if machine[:hostname] == "manager"
        node.vm.provision "docker",
          images: ["ubuntu/bionic64"]
      else
        node.vm.provision "docker"
      end
      node.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
        vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", machine[:ram]]
      end
    end
  end
end
```

## Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

RUN apt-get install -y python python-pip --no-install-recommends

RUN apt-get install vim -y

RUN apt update -y

ADD app /home/app/

WORKDIR /home/app

EXPOSE 8080
```

## Exception/Error Output Message:

The following SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status.
Vagrant assumes that this means the command failed!

curl -sSL https://get.docker.com/ | sh

Stdout from the command:

- Executing docker install script, commit: 02d7c3c

Stderr from the command:

Either your platform is not easily detectable or is not supported by this
installer script.
Please visit the following URL for more detailed installation instructions:

https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/

Comment: Is there a reason you need Ubuntu 18? It's not officially supported which is why I assume you are getting the error telling you as much, see: https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/ "To install Docker CE, you need the 64-bit version of one of these Ubuntu versions:

Artful 17.10 (Docker CE 17.11 Edge and higher only)
Xenial 16.04 (LTS)
Trusty 14.04 (LTS)"

Comment: @ldg I just needed to experiment with it. but in that case. i will just wait for it when get full support.

Comment: You could try installing it with your own install script but unless you had a really good reason otherwise it's better to use a supported version so you don't have to do a lot of potential workarounds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out spawning virtual servers with Ubuntu 18, using Vagrant. The link has all the simple instructions: [Spawn virtual servers on the fly](https://github.com/sean-huni/Jumpers)